# inboard drag and drop between stages iOS

Tags: swift, trello, kanban

I'm trying to do Trello like iOS app. With drag and drop boards/cards from one stage to another.
Does anybody knows any libraries that I can use to simulate that drag and drop process for swift 4? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score -2):

How about this library for dragging and dropping:

https://github.com/mmick66/KDDragAndDropCollectionView

Comment: I'm intrigued why this is down voted - would be good to understand why?

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to implement it) Also I have no clue why it's down voted for question and answer too. :(

Comment: @Adahus It's a link-only answer to an off-topic question. See Nr. 4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and the fifth bullet point here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Thanks @anothernode. Useful to read those links and I can see that this type of dialogue could lead to spam. Thanks for explaining. I will avoid in future.